# Node and Pod locking for Kubernetes autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

Running in Kubernetes I have a Deployment with autoscaling based on [Keda](https://keda.sh/).

This Deployment runs long running tasks of several hours and moving to jobs is currently not an option.

Is there any way in Kubernetes to lock a node and/or pod while the long task is running to prevent them from terminating due to down scaling during the long tasks are running?

The only option I currently am aware of it using a long `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` and making sure the pod exists once the task ends.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [podDisruptionBudget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/) to achieve that. It will make sure a certain number of pods should always remain online and nodes containing these pods cannot be deleted as long as they don't have a replacement online.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out!